# Escaping characters without using MySql functions in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, escaping

This question is about a clarification. I have a `varchar`-like table field in a MySql database which may contain single quotes in its value.

I need to perform some queries similar to:

```
select my_field
from my_table
where my_field = 'xxx'rrr';
```

Of course, the above does not work in MySql Workbench.

I have tried:

```
select my_field
from my_table
where my_field = 'xxx''rrr';
```

and

```
select my_field
from my_table
where my_field = 'xxx\'rrr';
```

They both seem to work from MySql Workbench.

However, these queries are crafted and executed in a PHP application.
I would like to know whether there is a possible caveat or whether I can use any of the methods above? What is the right way to escape single quotes without using MySql functions?

Comment: isn't the right way *not* to escape but use parameters instead? however, when inserting data you are *actively aware* of, as in the MySql Workbench, i'd say the right way is whichever way works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could escape characters. Both of your suggestions are correct. Here's what the [**official documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences) says:

> There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
>
> A ' inside a string quoted with ' may be written as ''.
>
> A " inside a string quoted with " may be written as "".
>
> Precede the quote character by an escape character ().
>
> A ' inside a string quoted with " needs no special treatment and need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, " inside a string quoted with ' needs no special treatment.

To answer your question, there is no correct or incorrect way of escaping characters in a query nor any caveats - as long as you follow one of the above approaches.

---

For creating queries in php however, you don't need to do any of the above; the code handles this for you. Here's an example using [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php):

```
$some_variable = "'a'string'with'single-quotes'";
$query = "SELECT my_row FROM my_table WHERE some_column = :some_value";
$values = array(
  "some_value" => $some_variable,
);
$result = $db->get($query, $values)->fetch();
```

You could also use [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) should you prefer that.

Comment: Updated my answer. Noticed a small mistake in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping with backslash works. 
This is an example from one of my projects:

```
select * 
from articles
where title like '%O\'Neill%'
```

Maybe you should use `like` just in case you have some spaces you can't see.

**EDIT:** escaping with backslash works, it's not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in PHP, you could you double quotes like this:

```
where my_field = "xxx'rrr";
```